# If $ a-b \mid ax-by$, then $\gcd(x,y) \ne1$?

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

So is this true for positive integers $a,b,x,y>1$ with $a>b$ and $x>y$?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lulu if the property in the title is true? Just double checking if there are some unintuitive conterexamples.

Comment: Note sure what your question is. The best I can interpret is if $a-b$ divides $ax-by$, then what can be said about the $\gcd(x,y)$? Just choose $a=b+1$ and then you have no restrictions on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I have no idea what property you are thinking of.  If, say, $a-b=1$ then $a-b$ divides $ax-by$ no matter what $x,y$ are.  Is that relevant?  And what does "=/=1" mean?

Comment: Ok. Thanks, definetly the case where a-b=1 is something to keep in mind, but are there other cases for which this doesn't hold?

Comment: @lulu by "=/=1" I mean not equal to 1.

Comment: @Anurag A yeah, you got it; the question is if that implies allways that x,y are coprime.

Comment: Use `$\ne1$` for $\ne1$

Comment: $ax-by=k(a-b)\Leftrightarrow x(a-b)+xb-by=k(a-b)\Leftrightarrow b(x-y)=(k-x)(a-b)$ so $(x-y)|(a-b)$ if $b\not|(a-b)$ and that's all. Say $x-y=3$, $y\ne 3$ (alternatively $y=3$) and $a-b=3$, @fisurafilozofica

Comment: But how could it imply that $x,y$ were always coprime?  If $(a-b)\,|\,(ax-by)$ then $(a-b)\,|\,(a(2x)-b(2y))$, and of course you could replace $2$ by any integer.

Comment: @lulu yeah, I forgot to a "not", I ment to say that it implies that they are not coprime. But Alexey Burdin found the cases for which it not holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well  $a-b|ax - bx$ and $a-b|ax-by$ so $a-b|(ax-bx) - (ax-by)=b(y-x)$ and ... why not?

So we can have $a-b |b$, for example $a=8;b=6$ and $x,y$ can be anything....$y=57, x = 56$ for example.   $8-6|8*57-6*58$.

And even if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ where can still have $a-b|y-x$ with no issue.  Let $y = 81$ and $x=73$ and $a=13$ and $b=9$.  Why the heck not?  $13-9|13*81 -9*73$.   Whoa! wait is that true?  $13*81-9*73 = 4*81 + 9*81-9*73 =4*81 + 9*4$.... yep, seems to be true.

Comment: THen reverse the order.  Let $x=56$ and $y=57$.  You still have $8-6|8*58-6*57$.  Let $x=81$ and $y =73$ then $13-9|13*73-9*81$.  "I have shown that OP's requirements are inconsistent"  I don't see why.  I just gave two counter examples.

Comment: Not to mention there's nothing to indicat $ax -by$ needs to be positive.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Say $a=b+1$, then $x,y$ can be anything.

Still no, say $a= 4$ and $b=2$, again $x,y$ can be anything.

Comment: Ok, but if the difference is greater then 1, the property holds?

Comment: Well in the case of 4, 2 it holds for all x and y, since gcd(4,2)=2 different from 1.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. It definetly does not hold if the integers are smaller than 1. But x is greater than y so we can't have the two be equal.